# "ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value" when trying to run Java jar file

Tags: java

I typed in "java -jar ShowTime.jar", and got this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 1347093252 in class file ShowTime
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
```

How should I fix this?
P.S. I have a mac.

Comment: Please provide details on your build environment, process, etc.

Answer (score 22):

A Java class should start with the magic (hex) value `0xCAFEBABE` (neat huh).  Your value `1347093252` is `0x504B0304` in hex, which happens to be the magic value for a ZIP file (first 2 bytes in ASCII are PK for [Phil Katz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phil_Katz), creator of the ZIP format).  A jar is also a zipfile btw, so probably your jar is pretty much corrupt.  Try rebuilding the entire project.

Comment: what else would a lonely programmer think of?

Comment: @jesus i'll settle for 0xC0FFEE

Comment: I am confused by what you mean.  I tried starting it all over, but it just keeps saying the same thing.

Comment: @user8 what I mean is that for some mysterious reason the file Showtime.class inside Showtime.jar appears to be a zipfile and not a .class file.  Without details about your build environment and how you created that jar it's impossible to say how that happened.

Comment: I have a mac os x, and so I compiled it with the terminal command 'jar cmf manifest.mf Showtime.jar *.class'

Comment: compiling a class requires javac.  FVU is suggesting that one or more .class files is bad.  delete them and recompile them (them being the class files) using javac.

Answer (score 1):

That usually means that you compiled the jar for a newer version of java than you ran it with. Check to see if you are using the same version of java to compile and run. If that doesn't fix the problem, please provide more info such as the compiler command and the output of `java -version`.

Comment: Both my Java and Javac are the same version (1.6.0_24)

Comment: I also had this, except with 1.8.0_65

Comment: so how to fix it ? how can I check if Im using the same version

Answer (score 1):

It means your application is using a jar file which is complied in a specific format in some other system. Now when you are trying to use the project in other system, the other system is not able to decode the jar, as each system generated a specific key to bundle the project.

Remote debug id the best way to find the issue that which jar is not in the proper format. Run the command in comment prompt for remote debug

java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8001,suspend=n (command and parameter to run you jar)

what you need is, find the jar file and replace with another jar (may be a freshly downloaded one or if you teammate has the jar. Use it.)

The error i was getting because my project way having dependency with another project ABC, and ABC was using a generic jar. But project ABC was bundled with the magic key. I have replaced the jar used by ABC with a downloaded jar.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when the main class name of my jar was not identical to its filename.

For example, the main class of the jar was named Foo.java, and inside it I had `public class Bar { ... }` instead of `public class Foo { ... }`

It is probably not the most general answer, but making the file name and the class name identical solved this issue for me.