# Tomcat ClassFormatError with default ContextListener

Tags: java, tomcat, listener, server

Long time reader, first time asker.

I've installed Tomcat on a RedHat box, and I can get it to respond when I go to the default page. I can even deploy a web app, no problem.

Except... Every time the server is restarted (even with no deployed web apps except for the default ones), it spits out a bunch of messages about failed listeners and an incompatible magic value.

This is an issue because I have a listener in my web app that I need to run, but because the other ones are are failing, no listeners are getting loaded.

I'm fairly sure that the issue is a bad library, but I can't figure out which one.

Here's the error message:

```
Dec 11, 2014 3:56:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class listeners.ContextListener
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 1061109567 in class file listeners/ContextListener
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:529)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:511)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4888)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1247)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1898)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Dec 11, 2014 3:56:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class listeners.SessionListener
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 1061109567 in class file listeners/SessionListener
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:529)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:511)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4888)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1247)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1898)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Dec 11, 2014 3:56:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class websocket.drawboard.DrawboardContextListener
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 1061109567 in class file websocket/drawboard/DrawboardContextListener
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:529)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivile
ged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:511)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4888)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1247)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1898)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1247)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1898)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Dec 11, 2014 3:56:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
```

My server.xml (license / comments removed):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>
  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

I've tried removing / re-installing Tomcat and changing the java version (first 1.7, then 1.6), but no luck. After several hours of searching SO (and Google) trying to find an answer to this, I'm at my wits end.

I would greatly appreciate any help that anyone could give me.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like Tomcat is trying to load class-files which are not class-files (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6797296/3080094)), i.e. some file(s) are corrupt. Oddly enough 1061109567 appears to be the [infinity](http://www.dmoj.ca/problem/infinity) number.

Comment: I agree, I just wish I could figure out which ones are bad. I tried replacing them all with ones downloaded from a different archive (I did that right before I did the remove / re-install), but it didn't help.